# Why doesn't pyautogui hotkey work all of the time on mac?

Tags: python, pyautogui

I am trying to use pyautogui to paste something that is copied to the clipboard.

This is my code:

```
for i in range(100):
    pyautogui.hotkey("command", "v")
    pyautogui.press("enter")
```

However, there are at least 4 or 5 times out of every 100 where something like 
"test
test
test
test
v
test
test
test"
is printed.

It seems like the problem is that the "v" key is being pressed before the "command" key. Is this a known problem and are there any solutions to this problem?

I have tried using

```
pyautogui.keyDown('command')
pyautogui.keyDown('v')
pyautogui.keyUp('command')
pyautogui.keyUp('v')
```

and adding

```
time.sleep(1)
```

inside the for loop, but nothing seems to work.

I am running macOS Mojave and Python 3.7.2.

Answer (score 0):

Yeah it doesn't work when you move with touchpad or hold other keys. If you don't touch anything there will be no issues

Answer (score 0):

This is my code for copypasting

```
    import pyautogui as p
    from time import sleep as t

    p.keyDown("command")
    p.press("v")
    t(2)
    p.keyUp("command")
    p.typewrite("v")
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).